# How to replicate excel solver in R

Tags: r, excel, mathematical-optimization

I used excel solver to solve an optimization problem, and I am trying to replicate it in R.

I found many packages like optim, ROI etc., but it seems all of them only take a vector as the object to optimize and allow the variables to take any continuous value. In my case, I have a constraint matrix that also needs to be satisfied and my variables can only take binary values.

Here is problem I want to solve:

A-D are machines, 1-3 are tasks and the number in the first matrix is the value generated by using X machine to do Y task. The constraints are: A-D can do and only can do one task (cannot split); each task can be worked and only be worked by one machine.

Here is the code I am using:

```
par = rep(c(0,1),6)

mat <- matrix(c(9,10,11,4,5,10,1,3,5,7,5,4), nrow = 3)

fr <- function(x) {  
  y= matrix(x,nrow = 4)
  sum(mat %*% y)
}

a = optim(par, fr)
```

Some questions: How can I optimize maximum, seems this function default optimize minimum? How can I add constraints into it? How can I limit to binary variables?

Comment: A matrix is a misshapen vector; reshape it and you're good to go (assuming you understand how to code up optimization of a vector). `xmat = matrix(1:4,ncol=2); x = c(xmat)`

Comment: Thanks Frank! I tried that and it worked. But I have some follow up question. I am indeed don't know how to code up optimization for a vector.

Comment: simply add a "-" minus sign to sum funtion, optim will maximize.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to construct a vector for the objective function and a constraint matrix, finally solving with one of the R LP solvers:

```
library(lpSolve)
costs <- matrix(c(9, 10, 11, 4, 5, 10, 1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 4), nrow=3)
nr <- nrow(costs)
nc <- ncol(costs)
columns <- t(sapply(1:nc, function(x) rep(c(0, 1, 0), c(nr*(x-1), nr, nr*(nc-x)))))
rows <- t(sapply(1:nr, function(x) rep(rep(c(0, 1, 0), c(x-1, 1, nr-x)), nc)))
mod <- lp("max", as.vector(costs), rbind(columns, rows), "<=", rep(1, nr+nc), binary.vec=rep(TRUE, nr*nc))
```

Now you can grab the solution and the objective function:

```
mod$objval
# [1] 27
matrix(mod$solution, nrow=nr)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    0    0    1
# [2,]    1    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    1    0    0
```

Note that functions like `optim` are not well suited for this problem both because they don't consider matrices of constraints and also because they cannot limit to binary variable values.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain how this whole thing works? Especially why `columns` and `rows` have to be repetitive.

Comment: @riders994 Basically `rbind(columns, rows)` returns the constraint matrix for the linear program, `rep(1, nr+nc)` is the right-hand side, and `as.vector(costs)` is the objective function. I used `rep` and other R functions to construct the constraint matrix for this particular linear programming problem. If you had a different problem you would probably use different code to get that matrix. You can read up on `rep` from its help page: `?rep`.

Comment: @josliber Would you be able to guide on a similar problem . It will really be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/72238988/8019264